# How to install HTML (Gecko) support in Wine?

Tags: firefox, wine, html, ie

I'm trying to run a game installer which requires me to scroll down a license agreement before being able to continue, it is rendered in HTML using some IE tech so I need wine-gecko I believe.. but how do I install it?

`wine msiexec /i wine-gecko-2.47.1-x86_64.msi` just gives me:

```
0009:err:mscoree:LoadLibraryShim error reading registry key for installroot
0009:err:mscoree:LoadLibraryShim error reading registry key for installroot
0009:err:mscoree:LoadLibraryShim error reading registry key for installroot
0009:err:mscoree:LoadLibraryShim error reading registry key for installroot
```

Not being able to scroll means not being able to agree to the licence agreement.

---

See: https://wiki.winehq.org/Gecko

I'm running Ubuntu 20.04.

### EDIT #1

When wine initializes itself I get this:

```
wine: created the configuration directory '/home/myuser/.wine'
0012:err:ole:marshal_object couldn't get IPSFactory buffer for interface {00000131-0000-0000-c000-000000000046}
0012:err:ole:marshal_object couldn't get IPSFactory buffer for interface {6d5140c1-7436-11ce-8034-00aa006009fa}
0012:err:ole:StdMarshalImpl_MarshalInterface Failed to create ifstub, hres=0x80004002
0012:err:ole:CoMarshalInterface Failed to marshal the interface {6d5140c1-7436-11ce-8034-00aa006009fa}, 80004002
0012:err:ole:get_local_server_stream Failed: 80004002
0014:err:ole:marshal_object couldn't get IPSFactory buffer for interface {00000131-0000-0000-c000-000000000046}
0014:err:ole:marshal_object couldn't get IPSFactory buffer for interface {6d5140c1-7436-11ce-8034-00aa006009fa}
0014:err:ole:StdMarshalImpl_MarshalInterface Failed to create ifstub, hres=0x80004002
0014:err:ole:CoMarshalInterface Failed to marshal the interface {6d5140c1-7436-11ce-8034-00aa006009fa}, 80004002
0014:err:ole:get_local_server_stream Failed: 80004002

Could not find Wine Gecko. HTML rendering will be disabled.
Could not find Wine Gecko. HTML rendering will be disabled.
wine: configuration in L"/home/myuser/.wine" has been updated.
Could not find Wine Gecko. HTML rendering will be disabled.
0009:err:mshtml:create_document_object Failed to init Gecko, returning CLASS_E_CLASSNOTAVAILABLE
```

So it looks like it's trying to find gecko somewhere..

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Download the latest Gecko files for your Wine version at https://wiki.winehq.org/Gecko. So if you have Wine 5.* you should download:

- [wine-gecko-2.47.1-x86.msi](http://dl.winehq.org/wine/wine-gecko/2.47.1/wine-gecko-2.47.1-x86.msi)
- [wine-gecko-2.47.1-x86_64.msi](http://dl.winehq.org/wine/wine-gecko/2.47.1/wine-gecko-2.47.1-x86_64.msi)

And you do need both x86 and x86_64 for this to work, but there is no need to download the `.tar.bz2` versions, `.msi` is what you want.

Then put them into the `~/.cache/wine/` directory and initialize/run Wine for the first time, such as by running `wineboot` or `wine someapp.exe`, but make sure you don't already have a `~/.wine/` directory, if you do have one Wine won't install Gecko.

But of course don't delete the `~/.wine/` directory if you have important files there!

Comment: What does "initialize wine" mean? It doesn't seem to just be starting it. I copied the folder to the specified directory and it had no effect on the issue.

Comment: @nwp I've clarified the answer for you.

Comment: Running `wineboot` once solved the issue.