# Ubuntu 18.04 not detecting wine gecko

Tags: wine

I downloaded `wine-gecko-2.47.1-x86.msi` and I moved it to `use/share/wine/gecko`.

I then try the command `wine msiexec /i wine-gecko-2.47.1-x86.msi`

And I get

```
0009:err:mscoree:LoadLibraryShim error reading registry key for installroot
0009:err:mscoree:LoadLibraryShim error reading registry key for installroot
0009:err:mscoree:LoadLibraryShim error reading registry key for installroot
0009:err:mscoree:LoadLibraryShim error reading registry key for installroot
```

Then when I try to install Java on wine, I get the following:
`Could not load wine-gecko. HTML rendering will be disabled.`

Does anyone know how to properly install gecko on Ubuntu 18.04?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: As mentioned [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1236824/181442), download the correct version (2.47 for wine 3.0-1ubuntu1 which comes with Ubuntu 18.04) and put them into the `~/.cache/wine/` folder. Then re-start your Windows program. I didn't need to run `msiexec`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to install HTML (Gecko) support in Wine?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1236811/how-to-install-html-gecko-support-in-wine)